# Spivak sum of three numbers

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to study calculus on my own, and in the very first page of Spivak's Calculus he states that "For the sum of three numbers, a, b, and c, this may be done in two different ways [...] a+(b+c) or  [...] (a+b)+c"

My question: is there a reason for him not to consider the case (a+c)+b? I would think that as another way to perform the sum of three numbers, so I'd say there are actually three ways to sum three numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: perhaps he is merely trying to illustrate the associative law for addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spivak's introduction gives you a feel for how certain "obvious" properties may not be obvious at all. These different ways of evaluating the sum of three numbers relate to the property of associativity. Not all operations satisfy this very natural property, so it is important to be careful.

A different property which you bring up in your question is the idea of commutativity (whether $a+b = b+a$), and indeed it may not be true that the objects you are working with commute! For addition of real numbers, it is true that they satisfy both associativity and commutativity, but I believe Spivak provides these to you as axioms (fundamental "truths" that you can accept) in the following pages.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually $12$ ways, if one counts all $3!=6$ possible permutations of $a,b$, and $c$ and, for each of them, both possible ways of parenthesizing the expression. However, he is interested here specifically in the associative property of addition, the one that says that for all $a,b$, and $c$,

$$a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c\,.\tag{1}$$

In other words, it says that adding from right to left always gives the same result as adding from left to right. It’s this fact that allows us to dispense with parentheses altogether and write simply $a+b+c$, something that we **cannot** do with subtraction: $(a-b)-c$ is not in general equal to $a-(b-c)$.

It’s important to separate this from relations like

$$a+(b+c)=(a+c)+b\tag{2}$$

that also involve changing the order of the numbers themselves, because there are mathematical operations that satisfy $(1)$ but not $(2)$. One of them is matrix multiplication: if $A,B$, and $C$ are $n\times n$ matrices, it’s always true that $A(BC)=(AB)C$, but it is **not** always true that $A(BC)=(AC)B$, because it’s not always true that $BC=CB$.